# Excel VBA For each sheet get contents of a row and put in an array

Tags: vba, excel

I have a current project that requires me to open an excel doc, figure out what format the doc is in (what the "headers" are as A:A contents), then figure out if it adheres to a new document layout format, and convert necessary data to conform to the new format.

I have to do this for thousands of files, so I want to automate as much of the discovery portion as possible, and plan to only need to write a few one-off solutions for some content types (docs with specific data which needs to be preserved as an exception to the new formatting).

That's the context for what I'm trying to do. I've gotten to the point of trying to populate an array of the contents of row A:A in each sheet, but my ReDim statement is failing as I guarantee I'm doing something wrong with it.

Here's what I've got from the point where I get into the sheet:

```
For Each Sht In SourceWorkbook.Sheets
    Sht.Activate
SourceHeaderCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
Set SourceHeaderRange = Sht.Range("A1:A" & SourceHeaderCount)
ReDim Preserve SourceHeaders(0 To UBound(SourceHeaders) + SourceHeaderCount)
SourceHeaders(UBound(SourceHeaders)) = SourceHeaderRange
Next Sht
```

Again, the idea is to grab the contents of A:A (used contents only), so that I have a list of what the file does have, then compare that list with what I need it to have, then from there I need to create sub functions to handle each type of conversion. First thing's first though, I need to know what the file has. Any ideas how I can make this work? I recognize that this approach has flaws when confronting non-standardized data (like what if a2 is unused but a3 is used?) but for the purposes of this context, assume all documents are easy to work with and there's no real strange data scheme to worry about.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find when aggregating a number of worksheets with similar (but non-conforming) layouts to a common worksheet, the brick-by-brick approach takes a little longer but it the most thorough. In the following, each sequenced worksheet has each column heading label examined to see if it already exists in the target worksheet. If not, it is inserted at the right-most end of row 1 and the cycle continues.

```
Dim r As Long, c As Long, tr As Long, tc As Long, ws As Worksheet, wst As Worksheet

Set wst = Sheets("All_of_Them")
For Each ws In Worksheets
    With ws
        If .Name <> wst.Name Then
            With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
                tr = wst.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1
                For c = 1 To .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                    If Not CBool(Application.CountIf(wst.Rows(1), .Cells(1, c).Value)) Then
                        wst.Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1) = .Cells(1, c).Value
                    End If
                    tc = Application.Match(.Cells(1, c).Value, wst.Rows(1), 0)
                    .Columns(c).Offset(1, 0).Copy Destination:=wst.Cells(tr, tc)
                Next c
            End With
        End If
    End With
Next ws

Set wst = Nothing
```

The above should be easily expanded to multiple workbooks in one or many folders. The target worksheet can start off as a blank worksheet and the aggregated column header labels will be constructed as new header labels are introduced with sequenced worksheets.

Comment: That does put the contents of one sheet onto another, but what I need to do is find cases where the data is called something different. Such as in doc 1 it's labeled "requirements" and in the new format the same data is labeled "certifications" so in that case, I would look for "requirements" and know that the data in there needs to be put under the new format "certifications" column.

Comment: @shagans - It sounds as if you need a cross-reference table that will translate the two. I suggest building a complete list of the available column header labels and assigning a new label value to each.

Comment: Yes that does sound like a good idea. What I'm trying to do is figure out how to dynamically build that complete list. Since I'm dealing with sheets that just have values in the top cells as the "headers" my attempt above was to build the array of those values which I intended to treat like a list of the column header labels used in that document.

Comment: Use the code above and comment the part that actually copies anything, leaving only the part that constructs the header labels across the first row of the target worksheet. When it is done, copy it and paste special, transpose to put it into a column. Work down the column supplying a new (or the same) value in te cell next to it.

Comment: well I was hoping to find a way to deal with all of the data manipulation in code, but I'll give this a shot and see if I can get it to work with what I'm doing. Thanks!

Comment: I was able to get this method to work. It's not quite what I wanted, but it gets the job done. Thanks a lot for the help!